# make regular expression all or nothing

Tags: php, javascript, regex

so I have this regex:

```
word1\/.+?\/word2($|[^\/]*)
```

I want this to match

```
word/2342/word2
```

But NOT

```
word/2342/word2/lalallaa
```

IE. as soon as word2 is followed by a slash, do not match AT ALL

Nonetheless, it would still match the 'word/2342/word2' part of the second regex... I want it to not match anything at all

How do I fix this regex?

Comment: Though I don't think I understand your question well enough, I can tell you from what I know about regex -- it will continue to parse an entire string until the end. I am unaware of any way to stop regex at a certain point -- though I have never had to research doing that.

Comment: Add a `$` after to make sure it's at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
word\/.+?\/word2$
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `($|[^\/]*)` with `(?!\/)`, or at least `($|[^\/])`. Right now, it’ll match any number of non-slashes — including zero.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried: `^(word1?\/.+?\/word2($|[^\/]*))` which worked in RegExr for mac, i entered : `word/2342/word2/word/2342/word2/` and it only matched the first `word/2342/word2` but this will only check if the string begins with what you asked... even a simple `(word)\/[0-9]{4}\/word2` will work and allow any 4 numbers in the middle.. but your question is confusing as to what you truly want from this?

Answer (score 0):

What about `(.+\bword2\b)(?!\/)`?

Answer (score 0):

In regex `/^abc$/`, the `^` is to find pattern only in the beginning of the string and the `$` is to find pattern only at the end of the string. Combined it will try to find a match with the whole string, it is like all or nothing match.

So put your regex to match in the string in the place of `abc`.